# signalr scaleout sending message to only particular client

Tags: signalr, scale

As I went through the documentaion of signalr scaleout options having a backpane, i see the backpane job is to send the message from one server to all signalr servers. If so, if Server 1 wants to send message to particular client, the message goes to backpane and from there to all other servers(ex. server 2,3)..where the client 1 is connected with Server 1. So can we restrict this to send only from server1 to client 1. Also the other question, are the events like connected, reconnected also will be routed to backpane and to all other servers ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SignalR backplane, all messages will be sent to all servers. There is no way to configure a SignalR scaleout provider to only send messages to specific servers. It's all or nothing.

If you choose to forgo a backplane, you could of course configure SignalR to use its default in-memory message store and then manually send inter-server messages.

Events like connected/reconnected/disconnected do not involve publishing messages so no messages will be routed to all other servers.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick info. But our problem is we have two servers with loadbalancer enabled, some clients will talk to Server 1 and some to Server 2, so backplane is the one option rt ??. But we don't have requirement to publish the message to all clients, but only to specific client. So the problem with backplane is the message once u broadcast to client only it will send to all servers rt.In that case each server should identify whether that client is connected with itself(using client-id to check) and send the message to that client.

Comment: SignalR backplanes do not support direct server-to-server messaging. Even if they did, it would be tricky since clients can reconnect to another server and request the messages they missed. For many applications, the backplane is not the bottleneck. There isn't much processing involved in retrieving a message from the backplane that doesn't need to be sent to a client. If it is too expensive for your application to send all messages to all servers, you are going to have to find a way to send inter-server messages yourself so you can avoid using a backplane.

Comment: hi just having one basic question on backplane(rabbitmq), when actually the service bus gets the message to send to all servers ? Is it only when we call Clients.All.X() method ?? it will go to all the servers ? Ex. If we have Server 1 and 2 via loadbalanced, both Servers has a method called SendMessage(), and this has code to call Clients.All or Clients.Client(dictionary[to]).X(). So when we call Server1::SendMessage(), then when will Server2 method of SendMessage() be called?? Is it like, when ever Clients.All or Clients.Specfic method is called, all servers will get the method be called?